# Any Idea on how Should I analyze this Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, python

I was wondering if I could get some help on how to analyze an algorithm, my teacher gave us the validation code for some strings. and out project is that we must create a keygen for this validator, and, of course, it must be true when validated. I have been trying by brute force, but I have no luck and It has been working like for 2 hrs. now, so any help, idea, or tip on how to solve this would be perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for the validator:

```
function char2number(chr) {
        var code = chr.charCodeAt(0); 
        if(code<65) code = code-48; 
        else {
             code=code-65+10; 
             if(code>=11) code++;
             if(code>=22) code++; 
             if(code>=33) code++; 
        } 
        return code; 
}

function checkdata(code) { 
        var dig = 0; 
        var test = 1; 
        for(var i=0; i<code.length-1;i++) { 
                dig=dig+(char2number(code.charAt(i))*test);   
                test*=2; 
         } 
        dig = mod(dig,9); 
        if(dig==code.charAt(code.length-1)) return true; 
        else return false; }

 function mod(X,Y) { var t; t = X % Y; return t < 0 ? t + Y : t; }

function valida() {
        var codigo = document.getElementById("code").value;
        // Validate the code
        if( code == "" || code.length < 15 ) {
           alert("Invalid!");
           return false;
        }
        if( ! checkdata(code.toUpperCase()) ) {
           alert("Invalid!");
           return false;
        }
```

This code is written in Javascript since we have to elaborate our solution in Python and, from python, call the service to validate.
I don't think that making the code is hard, but I 've been thinking on a way to solve this and I just can't find a pattern to get it to work.

Thanks, all!

Comment: What did you try? What is the question specifically?

Comment: From visual inspection: The line `if(dig==code.charAt(code.length-1)) return true;` looks suspicious; I'd expect a `char2number` in it. Disclaimer: I don't speak Javascript.

Comment: I just tried brute force by generating en 15 strings and trying to validate them, but with no luck. I still trying to analyze it but the only think I know is that i need to make that after all the math stuff for 'dig' the number must be the same as the ASCII for the last letter on the string.
Also, the code works fine, we saw it working with a string generator for it.

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider: Then show us that string generator, or a list of the strings it generated. And meanwhile, instead of throwing random strings at it, take some of the strings where you already know the result, and step through the code yourself trying to see _why_ that's the result.

Comment: @WolframH: In JS, you can compare a number to a string, and it automatically converts. So, for example, if `code` is `"12"`, then `2==code.charAt(code.length-1)` is true.

Comment: PS, what class teaches you to make keygens? It probably _is_ a good introduction to more professional/white-hat reverse engineering, but everyone I know who got that introduction did so by teaching himself as a 13-year-old pirate kid. (On 1MHz computers, in machine language, without this fancy internet, in the snow, uphill, both ways, and we liked it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, what's going on inside `checkdata`? Well, whatever it's doing before the end, after `dig = mod(dig, 9)` it's got a number from 0 to 8, and it's comparing that to the last character (`code.charAt(code.length-1))`). Notice that the `for` loop above does `i<code.length-1` rather than `i<code.length`, so that last character isn't included in the calculation. And (other than the check for length 15+) there's nothing else going on here.

So, you don't even have to understand what the whole `for` loop is doing. If you can generate 14 or more random characters, run the exact same code on them, and append the result to the end, it'll pass.

One quick and dirty way to do that is to just add an `alert` (or, maybe better, use `console.log` and run in node instead of a browser…) right before the end of `checkdata` that shows you what `dig` is:

```
function checkdata(code) { 
  var dig = 0; 
  var test = 1; 
  for(var i=0; i<code.length-1;i++) { 
    dig=dig+(char2number(code.charAt(i))*test);
    test*=2;
  }
  dig = mod(dig,9);
  alert(dig);
  if(dig==code.charAt(code.length-1)) return true; 
  else return false;}
```

So now, take some random string of 15 or more characters, like "ABC123DEF456GHI789". An alert will pop up saying "2", and it'll fail because 2 and 9 aren't the same. So just use "ABC123DEF456GHI782" instead, and it'll pass.

Now all you have to do is port that `checkdata` function to Python, change the `alert(dig)` to `return code[:-1] + dig`, write the code to generate 15-character random strings, and of course write the code that calls the service. But that's it.

By the way, porting to Python isn't always *quite* as trivial as it seems; for example:

- JS, `2` is a 64-bit floating point number; Python `2` is an unlimited-bit integer.
- JS strings are Unicode; Python 2.x strings are not (but 3.x are).
- JS strings in some browsers are actually UTF-16, not Unicode.
- JS `%` is sign-preserving; Python `%` is always-positive.

Fortunately, for writing a keygen, you can generate something that doesn't stray beyond the limits of where any of these things matters, but you should think things through to make sure you do so.

I should add that your teacher may want you to *understand* what's going on inside the `for` loop, instead of treating it like a black box. Also, in real life, whoever wrote this silly algorithm would figure out how you cracked it, and make a trivial change that made at least partially understanding the loop necessary (e.g., if they change the `<code.length-1` to `<code.length`).

Comment: Yes, this is true, but, in the `valida()` part, it's !checkdata, not just checkdata, (just noticed a few seconds ago), so, by changing the last character will result on 'Invalid'.
Here are some strings generated (without changing the last digit) as asked: 9ZM0Z25CPLBCK3Q, AVMVZPBGIX2N4HB, UWEEBTQVYBD9HZ7, G3WXRNBRGEUFN62. None of them works, and I don't have any working number, my teached said we didn't need. My generating function on python is:
`for times in range(15):
        code = code + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)`

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider: `if (!checkdata(…)}` it's invalid. Double negative. So you want to make `checkdata` return true for your string.

Comment: But I won't be making the validate function, that's already done by my teacher so I won't be able to touch it, I just finished the part where python calls the javascript function with selenium, but I just can't figure how to make it validate keys, whatever I throw to it comes back with a 'false' alert

Comment: Ok, while waiting I made the python script to check directly from my teacher's function the codes that it generates, but still with no luck, trying brute force atm. I'll keep trying to figure it oyt, as always, any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider: What part of my answer do you not understand? "Now all you have to do is port that `checkdata` function to Python, change the `alert(dig)` to `return code[:-1] + dig`, write the code to generate 15-character random strings, and of course write the code that calls the service. But that's it." Where does it say here that you have to make the validate function? You're changing your Python port of the instructor's `checkdata`.

Comment: @abarnert: Good answer! And nice spot on the off-by-one error.