# How long does it takes to check all possibilities?

Tags: python

I want to make a python program to run through a string in python:

```
a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

Will it take too long to find all possible 16-char combination for that string?

Is there a python-wise way to do it?

Comment: 36^16 = 7958661109946400884391936 possible combinations. Even with 10^12 iterations per second it would take you more than 250000 years.

Comment: What's your actual problem? What do you want to do with the combinations?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, no: C(36,16) = 36! / (16! * 20!) = 7307872110.

Comment: @larsmans: For me it looks like he's trying to bruteforce something. So repetition is most likely allowed.

Comment: @l4mpi It's a project, my last question got closed , was my first post and wasn't sure on how to post. But you can look at the details there: [My First Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076348/any-idea-on-how-should-i-analyze-this-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `combinations` from `itertools`.

Example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [x  for x in itertools.combinations("ABC", 2)]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

Comment: The OP wants combinations, not permutations.

Comment: @Jonatan Thanks for your help!, I was thinking is such many ways, but this is what i wanted. Any way to print them while checking for them? Because if I run `itertools.combinatios('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 16); I won't see anything in my lifespan, besides will it check ALL of the possible combinations?

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider, the combinations function is a generator, so you should be able to pick out as many combinations as you would like (for example using a for loop). The way I have written it with a list comprehension will pick out them all though.

Comment: @Jonatan Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!